# How do I run a Linux shell command from Octave?

Tags: linux, shell, octave

I want to run commands like `pdflatex` and `cp` from an octave script. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the function `system(<command>)` to call a shell command from Octave.  Replace `<command>` with the command you want to execute.  (Note that MATLAB allows a shell command to be executed by prefixing it with an exclamation mark `!`, but Octave does not support this syntax.  See this [Wikibooks page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Differences_between_Octave_and_MATLAB#Calling_Shells) for more information.)

Answer (score 1):

unix(command) is another way to go.  If you'd like to get properties of files directories etc. [Xoctave](http://www.xoctave.com/) does it automatically.

Comment: Just for example: unix('mv \*.\* ex1/')